# Auto adjust background color to cover whole container

Tags: css

I need to responsively show several images in a block container, how can I auto adjust and fill the whole container with specific color when screen size being narrowed. Below is the source code of HTML and CSS, demo can be viewed from http://jsfiddle.net/yckelvin/54v27shp/ Only the first few line are filled with the background-color, how can I fill the rest.

```
<div id="container">Smile Smile
    <ul>
        <li>
            <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-t9e7S8huhaQ/VBMVN6CbNGI/AAAAAAAAA14/02am46_jiJM/s1600/Big_smile.png">
        </li>
        <li>
            <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-t9e7S8huhaQ/VBMVN6CbNGI/AAAAAAAAA14/02am46_jiJM/s1600/Big_smile.png">
        </li>
        { rest content omitted }
    </ul>
</div>
<div id="container">Footer Footer</div>
```

CSS

```
#container {
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
    width:calc(100%);
    height: 100%;
    display: block;
}

img {
    width: 100px;
}

li {
    display: table-cell;
    float: left;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you don't clear your floats on your `li` tags. One way to fix that is to add clearfix snippet to your #container.

```
#container:after {
   content: " "; 
   visibility: hidden;
   display: block;
   height: 0;
   clear: both;
}
```

You can read more at - [What is a clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)

And you can check the working code here - http://jsfiddle.net/54v27shp/3/

Comment: Not only giving quick fix and also suggesting additional information, Also recommend to read http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Answer (score 1):

You can add `overflow:hidden` to your `container`.

```
#container {
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
    width:calc(100%);
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Or set the display of your `container` to `table` or `inline-block`

```
#container {
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
    width:calc(100%);
    height: 100%;
    display:table; // display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: adding overflow:hidden to parent element and ensure the parent block to cover all elements.

Answer (score 1):

Add `display: inline-block;` to `#container`

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pyoLq4y2/)**

```
#container {
    background-color: rgba(0, 255, 0, 0.2);
    width:calc(100%);
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block; /* or float: left; */
}
```

**OR:**

Add `display:inline-block;` to `li` and remove `display:table-cell;` and `float:left;` from `li`

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mxnqtvvh/)**

```
li {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/54v27shp/1/)

add a clear div after closing of `</ul>` the issue is because of float left for `<li>`

```
.clear{
  clear:both;
}

<div class="clear"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are experiencing is because the content of the #container is floated.

After your end UL-tag insert the following code:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Making the result:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-t9e7S8huhaQ/VBMVN6CbNGI/AAAAAAAAA14/02am46_jiJM/s1600/Big_smile.png">
    </li>
    <li>
        <img src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-t9e7S8huhaQ/VBMVN6CbNGI/AAAAAAAAA14/02am46_jiJM/s1600/Big_smile.png">
    </li>
    { rest content omitted }
</ul>
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```